# Reading data in an XML file and saving it to an array

Tags: java, xml, file-io, arraylist

I can't figure out why my following xml writer is not saving to the products array list. Instead my program is not adding anything to the list and using a debugger I see that the array list products value is always "size = 0". I'm not sure why this value is not changing as I am trying to add elements from an XML file to the list here is what my code to do that looks like:

```
private static ArrayList<Product> readProducts()
{
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    Product p = null;
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    try
    {
        //create a stream reader object
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("products.xml");
        XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(fileReader);
        //read XML file
        while (reader.hasNext())
        {
          int eventType = reader.getEventType();
          switch (eventType)
          {
               case  XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT :
                  String elementName = reader.getLocalName();
                  //get the product and its code
                  if (elementName.equals("Product"))
                  {
                     p = new Product();
                     String code = reader.getAttributeValue(0);
                     p.setCode(code);
                  }   
                  // get the product description
                  if (elementName.equals("Description"))
                  {
                     String description = reader.getElementText();
                     p.setDescription(description);
                  }    
                  // get the product price
                  if (elementName.equals("Price")) 
                  {

                      String priceS = reader.getElementText();
                      double price = Double.parseDouble(priceS);
                      p.setPrice(price);
                  }    
                  break;
               case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT :
                  elementName = reader.getLocalName();
                  if(elementName.equals("product"))
                  {
                    products.add(p);  
                  }    
                  break; 
              }
         reader.next();
        }    
    }
    catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e); 
    }    
     return products;
    }
```

Comment: `"Product"` is not equal to `"product"` ...

Comment: That fixed the problem thanks so much I don't know why I never noticed the p i've been googling stuff and going over my code for the past hour and its such a simple fix

Comment: No need to write all that tedious XML deserialization code yourself; this looks like a job for JAXB! http://jaxb.java.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your opening tag has the name `Product`, than the corresponding closing tag must be `Product` for it to be valid xml. Therefor you need to change

```
if(elementName.equals("product"))
```

to

```
if(elementName.equals("Product"))
                       ^
```

if you want to see your desired behaviour.